# Is Babel a compiler or transpiler?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've been using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) for a while now, and I've always been under the impression that Babel was a *transpiler* for converting my ES6 and ES7 JavaScript into ES5 JavaScript, as I was under the assumption that you could *technically* treat ES5 and ES6 as two different language.

However, I couldn't help but notice that Babel's website title describes it as a *compiler*, which I believe is something very different from a *transpiler*.

[image: Babel website title - 'Babel - The compiler for writing next generation JavaScript]

Is Babel a *transpiler* or a *compiler*, or perhaps offers both options? Or is the website's title simply incorrect?

*Disclosure: I know this sounds like a very pedantic question, but I am writing documentation relating to Babel, and I want to ensure my description is accurate*

Comment: A transpiler **is** a compiler.

Comment: Oh, I thought that a compiler converted source code into executable code, whereas a transpiler converted code into another language. So a transpiler is a form of compiler, then?

Comment: It is a transpiler, because a compiler changes HLL to LLL. But a transpiler is also sometimes called [source-to-source compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) so you could argue that babel is a compiler because transpiler is a *type* of compiler

Comment: The standard definition for compiler is something that translates between languages (though in common parlance it's usually used to denote cases where the target language is something like ASM or byte-code).  So that includes transpilers as a subset.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for the input. Both answers sufficiently answer my question, if either of you wish to submit an answer.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The definitions of "transpiler" and "compiler" are blurry. Both of them do [translate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translator_(computing)) a program from one language to another language while keeping the behaviour.

We usually name it a "compiler" when it produces an executable binary. However, binary is just another language, which can be interpreted by a CPU. Every program is "executable" on the respective machine.

We usually name it a "compiler" when it produces a lower-level output than the input was, e.g. C to assembler. Or Java to Java bytecode. Or ES8 to ES5. Wait… is that really a different level?

We usually name it a "transpiler" when its output is on a similar level as the input, e.g. Python to JavaScript or the other way round. However, there always will be parts that use an abstraction available in one language that need to be "compiled" to a lower-level implementation in the other language.

So to answer your questions:

> I believe a compiler is something very different from a transpiler.

No.

> Is Babel a transpiler or a compiler, or perhaps offers both options?

Yes.

> Or is the website's title '*Babel - The compiler for writing next generation JavaScript*' simply incorrect?

No. That title focuses on next-generation features, i.e. higher-level abstractions that really need to be *compiled* into a very different output. Even though the output is still ordinary, mostly human-readable, JavaScript.

> I am writing documentation relating to Babel, and I want to ensure my description is accurate

In that case, I'd use their own terminology from the official website. If you want to compare the tool to others, choose your own description.

Comment: I, and most of the Babel team AFAIK, think calling it a `transpiler` vs a `compiler` isn't a worthwhile distinction, so I just say compiler.

Answer (score 16):

Babel is a [transpiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler), which is a special type of [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), so both terms are techincally correct. You may use either at your preference.

It's irrefutable that Babel is a [source-to-source compiler (aka transpiler)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) since its source and target languages are both some flavor of JavaScript:

> A source-to-source compiler, transcompiler or **transpiler** is a type of compiler that takes the source code of a program written in one programming language as its input and produces the equivalent source code in another programming language.

However, not everyone agrees that the distinction between the terms is helpful, so some people prefer simply, "compiler".

I personally like the distinction because, to me, it implies something about the difference in *level of abstraction* from machine langauge between the source (input) and target (output) languages. That is, typical "compilers" translate from higher-to-lower level languages, "decompilers" translate from lower-to-higher level languages, and "transpilers" translate between languages at similar levels of abstraction.

Comment: takes the source code of a program written in a programming language as its input and produces an equivalent source code in the (same or a different programming language).
you forgot the same part in your answer however great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Transpilers, or source-to-source compilers, are tools that read source code written in one programming language, and produce the equivalent code in another language.

Babel is both a transpiler and compiler as the words can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, 'compiler' is defined as

> a program that converts instructions into a machine-code or
> lower-level form so that they can be read and executed by a computer.

So I personally disagree that Babel is a compiler but I don't really care if others use them interchangeably.