# Performance differences between transpiled ES2017 and compiled TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

I asked myself, if on a certain point any performance differences occure for transpiled *ES2017+* and compiled *TypeScript*?

This thought bubbled up, while considering the resulting JS, which is quite different (TypeScript's JS seems more straightforward, though).

**ES2017 code**

```
class TestClass {
  constructor(valueA) {
    this.valueA = valueA;
  }

  getValueA() {
   return this.valueA; 
  }
}
```

**Becomes**

```
"use strict";

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var TestClass = function () {
  function TestClass(valueA) {
    _classCallCheck(this, TestClass);

    this.valueA = valueA;
  }

  _createClass(TestClass, [{
    key: "getValueA",
    value: function getValueA() {
      return this.valueA;
    }
  }]);

  return TestClass;
}();
```

**TypeScript code**

```
class TestClass {
  valueA: any;
  constructor(valueA) {
    this.valueA = valueA;
  }

  getValueA() {
   return this.valueA; 
  }
}
```

**Becomes**

```
var TestClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function TestClass(valueA) {
        this.valueA = valueA;
    }
    TestClass.prototype.getValueA = function () {
        return this.valueA;
    };
    return TestClass;
}());
```

Comment: Note that there's no ES2017-specific code in your ES2017 example; it uses only ES2015 and earlier constructs.

Comment: Correct. But that's not the point.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are performance differences between the two outputs you quoted, although those performance differences are unlikely to matter. Babel's output uses several function calls, checks for various things, etc. TypeScript's output doesn't.

It's worth noting that the *reason* Babel does what it does is to do its best to ensure the correctness of the code it outputs. ES2015's `class` requires checks like requiring that the constructor be called via `new` or `super`; TypeScript's transpiled code doesn't do that.

Some of Babel's transforms have a "loose" mode that lets them output code that isn't technically correct, but results in faster code and in most cases has the same end result that correct code would have. For instance, if you use `es2015-loose` instead of `es2015` on that code, [you get this](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8BQ1rAHsA7ZAJwFdgkDSAKANzBHPgEEBKLXPaJACwCWEAHSNmbaAF5oYlqwDc3AL7ZuAc3hIAakzm1OOHqU3lSRXoJGy286MuxKgA&presets=es2015-loose) (I've done some word-wrapping):

```
"use strict";

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
    if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
        throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
    }
}

var TestClass = function () {
  function TestClass(valueA) {
    _classCallCheck(this, TestClass);

    this.valueA = valueA;
  }

  TestClass.prototype.getValueA = function getValueA() {
    return this.valueA;
  };

  return TestClass;
}();
```

...which is much more similar to the TypeScript output.

Comment: Ok, thanks so far. One thing: when it is also transpiled, why does the documentation define "Compiler options" https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html ? 
My understanding of "transpiling" is: bring one version of a language to another (older), and "compiling" is: translate one language to another (in this case TS to JS)

Comment: @scipper: Heh, as you were commenting I removed that parenthetical as too irrelevant. :-) They call `tsc` a compiler. It's just semantics. `tsc` and Babel do the same fundamental thing: They take in language X and output language Y. Whether you call that compilation or transpilation is largely up to you. I think the term transpilation is more accurate, because to me "compiling" is turning language X source code into machine code or at least an intermediary binary bytecode form (a'la Java and .Net), which `tsc` doesn't do.

Comment: Hmm ok. I can life with this ;)

Comment: +1 for mentioning loose mode. That [makes it](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8BQ1rAHsA7ZAJwFdgkDSAKANzBHPgEEBKLXPaJACwCWEAHSNmbaAF5oYlqwDc3AL7ZuAc3hIAakzm1OOHqU3lSRXoJGy286MuxKgA&presets=es2015-loose) look much more like the TypeScript output.

Comment: @scipper Also have a look at [Is Babel a compiler or transpiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43968748/1048572)