# What do those javascript front-end build tools mean when they say "compile" my js codes?

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, babeljs

I saw those javascript front-end build tools, e.g. webpack, using the word "**compile**" from time to time. I am not sure what does *compile javascript codes* mean exactly, at least not like compile c/c++ codes.

I think I understand the "build" process in general, like bundle all js codes into one big file, minify/uglify the codes, using babel to transforms ES6 syntax([transpile](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2012/11/compiling-vs-transpiling/)). But what does compiling mean here, how does it fit in the whole building process or it is just another name for the whole build process?

Currently, I thought it may be just another name for using Babel to transforms ES6 syntax.

PS. after reading this SO [Is Babel a compiler or transpiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968748/is-babel-a-compiler-or-transpiler) I believe my question is not same as that. Because it is not just related to Bable. For example, webpack also uses the term compiler https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler/ **I do not understand its meaning there**!

Browserify uses compiler as well e.g, https://github.com/robrichard/browserify-compile-templates "Compiles underscore templates from HTML script tags into CommonJS in a browserify transform"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Babel a compiler or transpiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968748/is-babel-a-compiler-or-transpiler)

Comment: @Yangshun Tay, it is not a duplicated question. See my update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's better to describe the process as "transpilation."

Javascript always executes in a specific environment: in Chrome and Electron, it's the V8 engine; in Firefox, it's SpiderMonkey; etc. Each of these engines supports a specific set of language features and not others. As an example, some engines only support `var` and do not support `const` or `let`. Some support `async`/`await`, and others only support `Promise`.

But web developers *know* about these other features, and they want to use them, even when they're writing for an engine that doesn't support those features. Why? Most new language features are designed with the goal of making it possible to express complicated concepts in simpler and cleaner ways. This is extremely important, because **the number one job of code is to make its purpose clear.**

Thus, most language features are essentially syntactic sugar for existing functionality. In those cases, it's always possible to express a routine using both new and old syntax. This is a logical necessity.

A transpiler like Babel can read a script written using advanced syntax, and then re-express the script using a restricted set of language features. Relying on an intermediate representation called an abstract syntax tree, it can produce code that is guaranteed to be functionally equivalent, even though it does the work using very different, more widely-supported control structures.

Perhaps we web developers have gotten lazy in our terminology. When we talk of "compiling" javascript, we aren't usually talking about converting the script to something like bytecode. We're talking about transpilation.

---

Other kinds of build tasks are also becoming quite common. These days, the front-end is obsessed with a million flavors of "templating," because it's extremely tedious and confusing to describe DOM changes using pure javascript, and because application complexity is increasingly very rapidly. Some frameworks require you to convert source code to other intermediary forms that are later consumed by the web application at runtime. Others permit devs to describe UI using invented syntaxes that no browser is even attempting to support natively. Which tasks are needed varies by application depending on which frameworks are being used, the particulars of the application architecture, and the contours of the deployment environment, and that's just a start.

At its foundation, a web page is built using HTML, CSS, and javascript. That much hasn't changed. But today, most serious applications are built almost entirely in javascript (or something very much like it) and sass. Building the application is the process of applying a set of transformations to the source code to yield the final artifacts in those three bedrock languages.

We lump all that stuff under the term "compile."

Comment: For all the answers I got so far yours is best so I marked your answer accepted. Thanks. I still got the impression that the "compile" just means the whole build process. But can you check the webpack document I provided I still don't understand what does webpack mean there.

Comment: Indeed it does. Javascript transpilation is often just one of many build tasks. If we're being sticklers, I'd say that "compile" is used to gloss transformation tasks only, excluding others like copying images and other static assets from their source location or updating manifests and other application metadata. Web developers as a group are gluttons for complexity.

Comment: But do you understand what webpack compiler does? I have no clue at all when reading its document.

Comment: Webpack's documentation is not always satisfying, because there is a widespread misconception that converting procedural logic to configuration somehow makes everything obvious. I believe Webpack Compiler is best described as a "task runner," like gulp or grunt, but built around the "config" paradigm. "Compiler" is the name of an abstraction that aims to obviate more of the procedural code that we used to use to configure and execute a build process.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much hit the nail on the head. When the Compile (or more appropriately transpilation) operation happens on a JavaScript project it can mean a number of things. As you mentioned these could range from minification, applying polyfills, shims, or the literal act of "compiling" the scripts into a single bundle file for platform/browser consumption.

Transpilation when using super sets of the JavaScript language such as TypeScript, ActionScript, or UnityScript describes the process of converting the source x-script back into native JavaScript which can be in turn be interpreted by a browser (since the browser doesn't recognize the superset languages).

However you are absolutely correct. We aren't compiling our JavaScript into binary, but the term gets thrown around a lot which can lead to confusion. All that said, we are closing in on the age of adoption of WebAssembly and ASMJs which promises to bring the age of bytecode running in the browser which will bring about some interesting possibilities, but alas... That's a story for another day ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're right when you say these front-end Javascript tools don't use the word compile in same context in what your used to with build tools for languages like C/C++. C/C++ compilers turn source code into machine code.

These JavaScript build tools-- like Webpack-- use the word compile in a sense thats more metaphorical than conventional.

When web build tools use the word compile, they're using it in the sense that they are transpiling, minifying (a.k.a uglyfying), and bundling the source files so they are better optimized for client browsers and network requests. (Smaller file sizes, better browser compatibility, less HTTP requests from bundled assets, etc.)